# Managing local and published extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am building an extension that will be available on a url, so I will use something like to help me manage the auto updating

```
 "update_url": "http://myhost.com/mytestextension/updates.xml"
```

I will obviously be building and testing locally first

I just wondered how people managed this.  I can of course create two manifests and then just use different ones at different times - is that the way to do this.  Ideally I would have two different names (so that when in Chrome I know which is my production and local one)

Thanks

Grant

Comment: How will your extension be available on a url?  Chrome no longer supports installing an extension not through the web store.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that after some research.  What I also found was that you can make an app private when you upload it to the store, so it is only accessible through a direct url, which is what I actually wanted

Answer (score 1):

In my organization I use update_url and local extension in developer mode.

When I publish a version of my extension I update the version of my local extension.

For example when I publish version 1.4.6, in update the local version to 1.4.7.
This my way to manage prod and dev versions.

See also [version name](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/version#version_name)

(I'm sorry about my english)